# Delete files after conversion in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm very inexperienced in Powershell - but through trial and error I have managed to get a .doc/.docx to .pdf conversion working well for a specified folder and all subfolders.

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*.doc"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\test-acrobat" -include $fileTypes |
foreach-object `
{
 $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 "Converting $path to pdf ..."
 $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
 $doc.saveas( $path, $wdFormatPDF)
 $doc.close()
}
$word.Quit()
```

Now I'd like to be able to delete the original .doc/.docx files once they've been converted. On doing some searching I've found what I think would work:

```
{
  remove-item $fileTypes  # delete file from file-system
}
```

But I'd rather check than throw in a command to delete files...

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Philip

Comment: Hint: `Remove-Item` has  the parameter `-confirm` to prompt for confirmation and `-whatif` to show what would happen. See: `help -full remove-item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the delete inside the foreach loop.

So you would get:

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*.doc"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\test-acrobat" -include $fileTypes |
foreach-object `
{
  $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
  Write-Host "Converting $path to pdf ..."
  $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
  $doc.saveas( $path, $wdFormatPDF)
  $doc.close()
  Remove-Item $_.fullname
}
$word.Quit()
```